# Black chart from chartjs-node-canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, charts, chart.js

I'm using chartjs-node-canvas lib in Protractor test (in JavaScript).
But somehow my chart is totally black (hard to say black, because I can see only the white frame of the square, without content). What I made wrong?

All code lines I put t afterAll part because my .json is a result of the measurement.
Because I imported my .json via fs.readFileSync I parsed it to use under my configuration like:

```js
 const getJson = fs.readFileSync(`file.json`);
 const json = JSON.parse(getJson);
const labels = json.map(function(item) {
        return item.a;
    });    
const data = json.map(function(item) {
        return item.b;
    });
const configuration = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: [labels],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'AAA',
          data: [data],
          borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          }]
      },
    };
const chartCallback = (Chart) => {
    Chart.defaults.global.hover.mode = "nearest";
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'VTKS UNAMOUR';
  };
```

My data seems to be ok, becasue as data and label I receive arrays of the values.
And finally I used it:

```js
const canvasRenderService = new CanvasRenderService(width, height, chartCallback);
const image = canvasRenderService.renderToBufferSync(configuration );
fs.writeFileSync(`chart.png`, image);
```

What I made wrong? png was generated as a blank page with a frame of a square.

PS according to https://github.com/SeanSobey/ChartjsNodeCanvas/issues/9 I tried with

```js
const chartjs = require('chart.js');
const canvasRenderService = new CanvasRenderService(width, height, undefined, undefined, () => chartjs);
```

But the same effect.

Comment: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2830#issuecomment-227867969

Answer (score -1):

I removed arrays from datasets and used CanvasRenderService without chartCallback. Additionally, the black background was resolved by mentioned in the github issue.